# SwiftyDropbox with AlamofireImage issue

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, dropbox, alamofireimage, swiftydropbox

I have the following line in my Podfile:

```
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.5'
pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 5.1.0'
```

When i run  `pod install`, i got this issue

```
Analyzing dependencies

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Alamofire (= 4.9.1, ~> 4.9)

  In Podfile:
    AlamofireImage (~> 3.5) was resolved to 3.6.0, which depends on
      Alamofire (~> 4.9)

    SwiftyDropbox (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      Alamofire (~> 4.8.2)
```

I read the solution of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295762/swiftydropbox-with-alamofire-issue) but it doesn't help .

Answer (score 2):

This issue will get resolved all you need to do is, install SwiftyDropbox first and then  Alamofire.